# Strange interaction on SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this query that can't be done when executed, it's just loading forever.

Here's more or less the overview of my query, just more column in my real query.

```
;WITH Person AS 
(
    SELECT OrderYear, PersonID, Name, OrderCount, OrderValue, OrderPoint
    FROM PersonTable
)
, PreviousYear AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.PersonID, 
        [PreviousYearOrderCount] = A.OrderCount,
        [PreviousYearOrderValue] = A.OrderValue,
        [PreviousYearOrderPoint] = A.OrderPoint
    FROM 
        PersonTable A
    JOIN 
        YearMapping B ON A.OrderYear = B.OrderYear 
                      AND B.YearFlag = 'PreviousYear'
)
, CurrentYear AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.PersonID,
        [CurrentYearOrderCount] = A.OrderCount,
        [CurrentYearOrderValue] = A.OrderValue,
        [CurrentYearOrderPoint] = A.OrderPoint
    FROM 
        PersonTable A
    JOIN 
        YearMapping B ON A.OrderYear = B.OrderYear 
                      AND B.YearFlag = 'CurrentYear'
)
, NextYear AS 
(
    SELECT 
        A.PersonID,
        [CurrentYearOrderCount] = A.OrderCount,
        [CurrentYearOrderValue] = A.OrderValue,
        [CurrentYearOrderPoint] = A.OrderPoint
    FROM 
        PersonTable A
    JOIN 
        YearMapping B ON A.OrderYear = B.OrderYear 
                      AND B.YearFlag = 'NextYear'
)
SELECT 
    X.PersonID, X.Name, D.Phone, D.Email,
    A.PreviousYearOrderCount,
    A.PreviousYearOrderValue,
    A.PreviousYearOrderPoint,
    B.CurrentYearOrderCount,
    B.CurrentYearOrderValue,
    B.CurrentYearOrderPoint,
    C.NextYearOrderCount,
    C.NextYearOrderValue,
    C.NextYearOrderPoint
FROM 
    Person X
LEFT JOIN 
    PreviousYear A ON X.PersonID = A.PersonID
LEFT JOIN 
    CurrentYear B ON X.PersonID = B.PersonID
LEFT JOIN 
    NextYear C ON X.PersonID = C.PersonID
LEFT JOIN 
    ContactTable D ON X.PersonID = D.PersonID
```

I tried to find which table is the problematic one and I found out it is table CurrentYear. If I Comment on this table --CurrentYear and get rid of select from that table and it is executable. Selecting this table alone only needing 4 Secs to execute.

After that I tried to insert that table to temp #CurrentYear and it works too. I tried inserting others table to #temp Ex.#PreviousYear and not using CurrentYear table and it works too. I Also tried to comment all others table except CurrentYear and it is also works.

Overall it took 28-30 Secs to finish and have 30k records.

Year Mapping is just table with value like this

```
YearFlag, Year
PreviousYear - 2018
CurrentYear  - 2019
NextYear     - 2020
```

At this point I'm so weirded out and confused with this interaction.
Any pointer or help would be appreciated.

Comment: create `index` in your tables for respected columns.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code?  I ask because the `GROUP BY` queries seem at a glance to be invalid, since you select columns not appearing in `GROUP BY`.  In any case, the above comment is correct and you should look to tuning the query if you want to improve performance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: try with this, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33749/sql-update-satement-taking-a-very-long-time-high-disk-usage-for-hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the common table expressions by temporary tables. Often the optimizer get's terrible confused by the use of multiple ctes.

You could even lose most of your code, like this:

```
;

    SELECT 
        A.PersonID, A.Name, A.Phone, A.Email,
        [PreviousYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'PreviousYear' THEN A.OrderCount ELSE NULL END ),
        [PreviousYearOrderValue] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'PreviousYear' THEN A.OrderValue ELSE NULL END ),
        [PreviousYearOrderPoint] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'PreviousYear' THEN A.OrderPoint ELSE NULL END ),
        [CurrentYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'CurrentYear' THEN A.OrderCount ELSE NULL END ),
        [CurrentYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'CurrentYear' THEN A.OrderValue ELSE NULL END ),
        [CurrentYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'CurrentYear' THEN A.OrderPoint ELSE NULL END ),
        [NextYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'NextYear' THEN A.OrderCount ELSE NULL END ),
        [NextYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'NextYear' THEN A.OrderValue ELSE NULL END ),
        [NextYearOrderCount] = SUM( CASE WHEN B.YearFlag = 'NextYear' THEN A.OrderPoint ELSE NULL END )
    FROM 
        PersonTable A
    JOIN 
        YearMapping B ON A.OrderYear = B.OrderYear 
    GROUP BY A.PersonID, A.Name, A.Phone, A.Email
```

Comment: It seems that the `WITH Person` CTE is never used now.

Comment: You're right. The CTE wasn't even used. D'oh. I've updated it and hope that now it's at least comprehensible pseudo code.

Comment: Found out CTE isn't really the best for performance, you inspired me to change my queries structures and it performs better.Thank you!